# Outlook font size for add in

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, add-in, font-size

I need help with the text size for my outlook add in.

I have a table view in my add in which is unreadable with bigger screen resolutions. Is there a way to zoom so the font size gets bigger?

With a selected email from my inbox it is possible to zoom with the zoom slider in the bottom right corner. Is there a way to activate the zoom slider at any time? Or is there any way to access and change/set the font size outside of the email body?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your add-in is not DPI-aware. Desktop applications using older Windows programming technologies (raw Win32 programming, Windows Forms, Windows Presentation Framework (WPF), etc.) are unable to automatically handle DPI scaling without additional developer work. Without such work, applications will appear blurry or incorrectly-sized in many common usage scenarios. To make things working better you must read the following articles:

- [High DPI Desktop Application Development on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows)
- [Writing DPI-Aware Desktop and Win32 Applications](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dn469266(v=vs.90))

Most probably the table view is used on a windows form, see [Automatic scaling in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/automatic-scaling-in-windows-forms) for more information.